# Unable to install PHP5-APC

Tags: php5, alternative-php-cache

When trying to install php5-apc, getting this error :

```
root@x-fr-1:/etc/apt# apt-get install php5-apc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-apc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 70.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 211 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://packages.dotdeb.org/ stable/all php5-apc amd64 5.4.23-1~dotdeb.1 [70.4 kB]
Fetched 70.4 kB in 0s (726 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 48129 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking php5-apc (from .../php5-apc_5.4.23-1~dotdeb.1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-apc_5.4.23-1~dotdeb.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/apc.so', which is also in package php-apc 3.1.13-1
Processing triggers for php5-fpm ...
[ ok ] Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager: php5-fpm.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-apc_5.4.23-1~dotdeb.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running Debian 7 Wheezy & PHP5-FPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflicting package, `php-apc` which you need to remove first, before replacing it with the third party package.

Start over:

```
apt-get remove php-apc php5-apc
```

Then try again:

```
apt-get install php5-apc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually:

```
apt-get install php-apc
```